# How to shorten multiple if conditions in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been putting images to my element img `src`. I have 4 file types to check, `.png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif`. What I want to achieve is whenever a filetype isn't available in the server, go and check other filetypes and replace the value of the `<img src="">`.

for example, if `.png` file isn't available in the server, check if `.jpeg` is available, if still not, check `.jpg`, and so on.

and if `.jpg` isn't available on the server, check `.jpeg` if available, if not, check `.png` and so on.

My current code only contains 2 conditions, and I'm thinking about how can I shorten my `if-else` if I were to put the other file types.

```
$('img').one('error', function() {
                if(this.src.includes(".png")){
                    this.src = this.src.replace(".png", ".jpeg")
                }else if(this.src.includes(".jpg")){
                    this.src = this.src.replace(".jpg", ".png")
                }
             });
```

I'm able to use lodash but I don't want to install another third-party package. I'm still considering a switch case statement but if an `if-else` statement will do and rather go with it. Thanks!

Comment: Is it your server?

Comment: No, it's from my handlebars file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can loop over the extensions and test one by one on each function call according to the current extension, here is the code

```
// define the supported extensions so you can add, delete and modifie
let supportedExtensions = ["png", "jpeg", "jpg", "gif"];

$('img').one('error', function() {
  // loop over the supported extensions
  for(let extension of supportedExtensions) {
    // if the current extension is the extension of the image
    // then get the next extension in the array but if the current
    // extension is the last one then get to the first one, finally break the loop
    if(this.src.includes("." + extension)) {
      let index = supportedExtensions.indexOf(extension) + 1;
      index === supportedExtensions.length && (index = 0);
      this.src = this.src.replace("." + extension, "." + supportedExtensions[index]);
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a live example, an image of a snowman drawing, the available extension is `.png` but in the **HTML** code the image has `.jpeg` as extension (for demonstration), but the program finds the correct one and logs the tries, note that in order to try multiple times you need to listen with `.on` instead of `.one` since you are not sure that the available extension is just the next one in the array!

```js
// define the supported extensions so you can add, delete and modifie
let supportedExtensions = ["png", "jpeg", "jpg", "gif"];

$('img').on('error', function() {
  // loop over the supported extensions
  for(let extension of supportedExtensions) {
    // if the current extension is the extension of the image
    // then get the next extension in the array but if the current
    // extension is the last one then get to the first one, finally break the loop
    if(this.src.includes("." + extension)) {
      console.log("Trying " + extension);
      let index = supportedExtensions.indexOf(extension) + 1;
      index === supportedExtensions.length && (index = 0);
      this.src = this.src.replace("." + extension, "." + supportedExtensions[index]);
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.drawinghowtodraw.com/stepbystepdrawinglessons/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/400x400-snowman.jpeg" width="150" height="200">
```

Comment: This is the correct approach! But the other answers gave me ideas. +1 to you @SaymoinSam!

Comment: Just to explain why this is my chosen answer is because it checks URL filetypes over and over again until it gets the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to match the extension. Check the below code:

```
ext = {".png": ".jpeg", ".jpg": ".png"};

$('img').one('error', function() {
   matched = this.src.match(/\.(png|jpg)/)
   if(matched){
      matched_value = matched[0];
      this.src = this.src.replace(matched_value, ext[matched_value]);
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

An object can be used as a look up with a replace

```js
var replacements = {
  "png": "jpeg",
  "jpg": "png"
};
var reImgs = new RegExp(`\\.(${Object.keys(replacements).join('|')})`);

function cleanUp(str) {
  return str.replace(reImgs, function(_, match) {
    var replacement = replacements[match] || match;
    return `.${replacement}`;
  });
}
console.log(cleanUp("/foo/bar.png"));
console.log(cleanUp("/foo/bar.jpg"));
console.log(cleanUp("/foo/bar.gif"));


$('img').one('error', function() {
  var src = this.src;
  const updated = cleanUp(src);
  if (updated !== src) {
    console.log("trying", updated);
    this.src = updated;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="foo.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could have an object like structure i.e

```
const typesArr = ['png', 'jpeg'];
const type = filename.split('.').pop();
const supportedTypeMap = {
    png: 'jpeg',
    jpg: 'png'
}
if (supportedTypeMap[type]) {
    // your replacing code.
}
```